# Blog rejected from AdSense for Insufficient content

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

My blog was published on September 10,2017. I have tried to place ads on this blog with Google Adsense on daily basis but I always get below generic reply. My blog is seen on daily basis by approx 6.5 users per day since it was published. But I am not sure why Adsense is rejecting my request with below generic reply. What I need to do to resolve it?

> As mentioned in our welcome email, we conduct a second review of your AdSense application once AdSense code is placed on your site(s).
>
> We did not approve your application for the reasons listed below
>
> Insufficient content: To be approved for AdSense and show relevant ads
> on your site, your pages need to have enough text on them for our
> specialists to review and for our crawler to be able to determine what
> your pages are about.
>
> To resolve this issue, please work through the following suggestions:
>
> - Make sure that your pages have sufficient text - websites that contain mostly images, videos or Flash animations will not be approved.
> - Your content should contain complete sentences and paragraphs, not only headlines.
> - Ensure that your website is fully built and launched before you apply for AdSense - do not apply while  your site’s still in a beta or “under construction” phase or only consists of a website template.
> - Place the ad code on a live page of your website. It does not have to be the main page, but test pages that are empty except for the AdSense ad code will not be approved.
> - Provide a clear navigation system for your visitors so that they can easily find all of the sections and pages of your website.
> - If you’d like to monetize YouTube videos, please apply for the YouTube
>   monetization program. Note that blogs and websites that contain only
>   videos will not be approved.

Comment: What to do is fairly clear. What is your question?

Comment: You need more pages.   I've heard that it requires about 50 blog posts to get approved for AdSense now.   It doesn't really matter anyway.  With 6.5 visitors a day you are going to make about $12 a year.   It will take you six years to reach the $100 threshold required to actually get a payment from AdSense.   For now focus on building your site and growing your traffic.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller You mean I need to post about 50 separate  blog post probably on different topics or I need to have 50 pages in same post ? Regarding  `With 6.5 visitors a day you are going to make about $12 a year` is there any stats clearly stated how much we get per click . From your stats looks like its `.5` cents per  click ?

Comment: @closetnoc what to do is not fairly clear. They have mentioned 6 points like content,grammar,navigation etc.  which are very generic. I am not sure which particular point is the pain point ?

Comment: Seems very clear to me. They are literally telling you what to look for in succinct bullets. One they could add is to have sufficient content with an idea of what that would be.

Comment: You need 50 pages of content.  For a blog, that is usually 50 different posts.  They can all be about the same topic (like beekeeping) but should be unique in focus (keeping from getting stung, collecting honey, care of your bee suit, etc).

Comment: For AdSense figure on a $2 RPM.   That is you make $2 per 1000 visitors.  RPMs depend on your category and ad placement.  They can vary between $1 and $6 but $2 is probably typical after optimizing your ad layout.  CPCs are usually between $0.20 and $0.50.